# How to scrape Legue Of Legends summoner ranking data, with Portia?

Tags: python, scrapy, portia, riot-games-api

*Hi everyone. My thesis project is about e-sport behavior analytics.
I have limited programming and data engineer skills.*

- I have a list of summoner names (the participants of the study)
- I try to scrape their ranking data from pages like "lolking.net"

  - there are different seasons (S1, S2 ...)
  - rank medal is marked by a .png, not a number or text. (this is the biggest issue)

*Lets see this with an example:*
[*sry for the big picture link, aim not allowed to embed*]

[Here is a picture of a summoner profile, and the items containing the information. 
I need,the main medal shows the actual Seasion (S7) rank picture (bronze_1). 
But there is hidden items also, which shows after clicking to the button marked by the arrow. After this the the HTML source, and the desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFBds.jpg)

*The desired output is like:*

> SUMMONER NAME;S1rank;S2rank;S3rank;S4rank;S5rank;S6rank;S7rank 
>   Shadowhuner;NA;NA;NA,NA;bronze_5;silver4;silver_2;bronze_1

Good people of StackOverflow, please help me to build this spider!
My specific issue:

## **How to address the selectors to the ranking data in Portia?**

- remember: there are hidden, or sometimes not, depending on the summoner's     play history. (basically: when they started to play)

Comment: One question per question please.

Comment: uhhh, i just noticed that is the entire problem, and too much question, i will edit soon, and thx for the advice

Comment: For anyone discovering this question: scrape data from the [Riot API](https://developer.riotgames.com/apis). The official and easy way to gather data.